# Tailwind CSS: Referencing Theme Colors When Creating Custom Class

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to modify the `tailwind.config.js` file to create some custom classes.  For example, I would like to create a color palette - and do so by referencing other colors in the theme.

To do so, I have made the following changes to the `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: (theme) => theme("colors.blue.500"),
      },
    }
    ...
```

This, however, does not work.  I don't get any errors - but I also do not get any custom classes either (even though, [according to the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme/#referencing-other-values), this should work).

On the other hand, this does work:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: "#abcdef",
      },
    }
    ...
```

This will create classes such as `bg-primary`.

Any idea how I can create custom classes by referncing other values in the theme?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your first example indeed doesn't seem to work. These don't work either:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: (theme) => ({
        primary: theme('colors.blue.500'),
      })
    },
  },
}
// → RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: (theme) => ({
      colors: {
        primary: theme('colors.blue.500'),
      }
    }),
  },
}
// → no error, but doesn't work

module.exports = {
  theme: (theme) => ({
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: theme('colors.blue.500'),
      }
    },
  }),
}
// → no error, but doesn't work
```

However, the [Customizing Colors](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors/) page has a section called [Overriding a single shade](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors/#overriding-a-single-shade) which contains the following example and explanation why your config and my configs above don't work:

> Since values in the `theme.extend` section of your config file are only merged shallowly, overriding a single shade is slightly more complicated.
>
> The easiest option is to import the default theme and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in the color you want to customize along with the new shade value:
>
> ```js
> // tailwind.config.js
> const { colors } = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')
>
> module.exports = {
>   theme: {
>     extend: {
>       colors: {
>         blue: {
>           ...colors.blue,
>           '900': '#1e3656',
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

So, here's how you can achieve what you are trying to do:

```js
const { colors } = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: colors.blue['500'], // 500 (number) would also work
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried this, and it seems to work. The built CSS file contains these classes (among others, of course):

```css
.bg-blue-500 {
  --bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: #4299e1;
  background-color: rgba(66, 153, 225, var(--bg-opacity));
}

.bg-primary {
  --bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: #4299e1;
  background-color: rgba(66, 153, 225, var(--bg-opacity));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To reference other values, it has to be in the top-level theme key, instead of individual value. Docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#referencing-other-values

For example:

```
// bad
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: (theme) => theme("colors.blue.500"),
      },
    }

// good
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: ({theme}) => ({
        primary: theme("colors.blue.500"),
      }),
    }.
```